# Store XML, update record in XML, retrieve a specific record in XML stored on BB device

Tags: xml, parsing, blackberry

I am writing a blackberry application where I want to store the
data returned by a web service in my BB device. Earlier I was going to
use SQLite for storing the data in mobile but as I googled and also did programming using SQLite and found
that some BB devices don't support SQLite library and fail to create the database. Then I decided to keep
the data returned by webservice in a XML format on my BB device.

I just want to know is there any method or way in blackberry through 
which i can parse the data stored in XML, update it, or directly access
a particular record stored in the XML instead of traversing the whole XML n times and finding the matched record.

Please guide me as I am new to storing data in BB device. Is the approach which
I am thinking to store data in XML right or shall I use something else?

Yogesh Chaudhari

Answer (score 1):

Hi there are many options depending upon your requirement and choice:

1) RMS - better to use if u r using midlets
2) Persistence  - for cldc
3) Sqlite   -  devices supporting OS 5.0 or later
4) File system - any device

Persistence: when u get your response in xml try to parse and fetch the components from it, save in a vector and persist that vector in device.You can fetch data from it any time.

File System - write your contents in a file and save in SDCard when you want read that file and use its contents.

You can download this book that can guide you well through code and concepts too

1) http://www.freshwap.net/3a8/dl/Apress+Beginning+BlackBerry+Development+Nov+2009+Pdf (not free)
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

these books can guide you in detail depending upon ur requirement
Moreover u can search stack overflow for similar questions and get variety of answers

Comment: hi swati thanks for your reply.I dont want to use Persistent as it has size limitations.An object stored in persistent store can be only of 64 KB and my application will need more space.SQLite dont support on all devices.Do u have any idea in which i can treat my xml like a database.Like say i have 10 records in xml and i have to directly retrieve the record at 5th postion,or i have to update the value of a particular attribute for a record.Thanks

Comment: yes persistence has limitations  & u can fetch the value of a particular attribute using xml parsers.Moreover after updating the record u must need to save it.Have u thought of using another databases other than sqlite?

Comment: hi swati.......I know only SQLite which can allow me to store data in mobile.Can you please tell me any other databases which i can use to store database in mobile?

Comment: Well i have heard about UltraLiteJ database but haven't used it.May be it can help u some way.

Comment: just wanted to knw -- u said u will get an xml file that u need to parse and fetch a specific record.Will u need to store that specific record or whole xml.did u tried with filesystem?

Comment: I will have details of all contacts in my XML.Suppose if the webservice changes the value for the particular record it will return me the same and i will fetch that particular record from the xml stored in my mobile in xml,update the value and restore it in the xml file on  mobile.This is what i want to do