# SAX parser in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, saxparser

My XML is in following format

```
<users>
  <user uid="1" dispname ="Yogesh C" statid="1" statmsg = "Busy">Yogesh Chaudhari</user>
  <user uid="2" dispname ="Sameer S" statid="2" statmsg = "Available">Yogesh Chaudhari</user>
</users>
```

In my BlackBerry app, I want to change the value of a particualar attribute, such as `statmsg` for uid 2.  Is it possible to do this using a SAX parser?  My aim is to update the XML and restore it.

I used the following code for parsing my XML using SAX:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class SaxParseUrl extends UiApplication {

    public SaxParseUrl() {

        pushScreen(new Pars());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SaxParseUrl app = new SaxParseUrl();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
}

class Pars extends MainScreen implements ContentHandler 
{
    boolean name;

    Pars() {
        try {
            XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
            parser.setContentHandler(this);
            FileConnection conn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/employee.xml");
            InputStream is = conn.openDataInputStream();
            InputSource iss = new InputSource(is);
            parser.parse(iss);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","Exception in pars() :"+e);
        }
    }

    public void startElement(String nsURI, String strippedName, String tagName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        try {
            debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","startElement");
            if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) 
            {
                debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","Inside startElement");
                name = true;

                String uid = attributes.getValue("uid");
                String dispname = attributes.getValue("dispname");
                String statid = attributes.getValue("statid");
                String statmsg = attributes.getValue("statmsg");

                attributes.

                //LabelField lb = new LabelField(uid+"==>"+dispname+"==>"+statid+"==>"+statmsg);
                LabelField lb = new LabelField("uid ==>"+uid+"\ndispname==>"+dispname+"\nstatid==>"+statid+"\nstatmsg==>"+statmsg);
                add(lb);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","characters");
        if (name) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Title: " + new String(ch, start, length));

                    LabelField lb=new LabelField(""+ new String(ch, start, length));
                HorizontalFieldManager sr=new HorizontalFieldManager();
                sr.add(lb);
                add(sr);


                    //v_cid.addElement(new String(ch, start, length));
                //System.out.println("the elements of vector: " + v_cid);



                // name = false;
                //Enumeration e = v_cid.elements();
                //System.out.println("The elements of vector: " + v_cid);
                //while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    //System.out.println("The elements are: " + e.nextElement());
                //}*/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","endDocument");
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String tagName)
            throws SAXException {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","endElement");
    }

    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","endPrefixMapping");

    }

    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","ignorableWhitespace");

    }

    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data)
            throws SAXException {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","processingInstruction");
    }

    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","setDocumentLocator");
    }

    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {

    }

    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","startDocument");
    }

    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
            throws SAXException {
        debug("file:///store/home/user/SAXParser.txt","startPrefixMapping");

    }

    public static void debug(String strFileName,String strData)
     {
        FileConnection fc = null;
        StringBuffer strbufData = null;
        OutputStream ops = null;

        try
        {   
            fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(strFileName,Connector. READ_WRITE);

            //create the file if it doesnt exist
            if(!fc.exists())
            {
                fc.create();
            }

            InputStream is = fc.openDataInputStream();
            strbufData = new StringBuffer();
            int intCh;

            while((intCh = is.read())!= -1)
            {
                strbufData.append((char)intCh);
            }

            strbufData.append("\n\n"+strData);

            String strFileContent = new String(strbufData.toString());
            byte byteData[] = strFileContent.getBytes();

            ops = fc.openOutputStream();
            ops.write(byteData);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Dialog.alert("Exception in writing logs :"+e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(ops != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ops.close();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
            if(fc != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fc.close();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code to get useful help.    Limit your code sample to a couple dozen lines.

Comment: Hi.i will reduce the code.But can u please tell me can we update the value of a attribute in XML using SAX.After my investigation i feel i cant change the value of a attribute directly using SAX.please help.

Comment: hi.I have finally updated the attribute value in XML using SAX parse.I have used the setValue method of the AttributesImpl class(org.xml.sax.Attributes).

Comment: Finally i have updated the XML but the drawback which i felt is even if attribute of one record is updated i have to reform the complete xml with n records and then rewrite it to device memory.I dont find it feasible to reform the complete xml and rewrite it to the device memory just for the sake of one record updation.Any suggesstions on this.If any one want the code regarding how i updated the attribute value please tell me i will post the code

Comment: The problems you are encountering are why people have been warning you against this. You've set the condition you MUST use xml files. So I guess you could parse the xml into a vector, perform reads from the vector and writes to the vector plus write transactions to xml in separate files. Recovery would then be read the master xml + your series of transaction xml's. At intervals you could take a checkpoint and commit all pre-checkpoint transaction xmls to a newmaster xml and upon success replace the oldmaster xml. Or you could just use persistent storage? :)

Comment: Thanks Ray Vahey.I completely agree with u and i myself want to go for persistent store.But the thing is i have very less time and cant immediately invest more time on exploring persistent store[as i am new to that too :( ].But i myself feel it will be more appropriate to use persistent store.I will definately explore persistent store as i get some free time.Thanks for ur suggesstion Ray Vahey :)

Comment: Hi user469999, if you have an answer to this question it would be good if you could add it as an official answer and then accept it (FYI, you have to wait 2 days to accept your own answer).  That way people will know this question is solved, and they won't need to read all these comment!  You'll also get rep points for answering your own question.  :-)